# Python: 'from module' vs. 'from__main__' weird behavior using timeit

Tags: python, module, program-entry-point, timeit

I'm learning python and I was just playing around with the timeit module when I realize a weird behavior I couldn't explain.

```
#test.py

import timeit

def dictComp(I):
    return {x: x for x in I}

t = timeit.timeit(number=5,
                  stmt='dictComp(I)',
                  setup='from test import dictComp\nI=range(1000000)')
print(t)
```

So I'm trying to time the creation of dictionaries with a dict comprehension, by calling a user-defined function.
But when I do that with the code above, timeit seems to execute twice.
The interpreter output two different times.

But when I change the setup string to be `from __main__` instead of `from test`, timeit runs only once (as expected).

So is there a difference between the two statements?
Is it wrong to write `from [module] import [obj]` when the module is the main module?
or does it have something to do with how the setup parameter of timeit works?

Please enlighten me. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__main__` module is not the `test` module, even though they come from the same file. When execution hits

```
from test import dictComp
```

`test.py` executes again, this time as the `test` module instead of the `main` module. (When execution hits that line a second time, `test` is already being imported, so the file doesn't run a third time.)

It's good practice to put stuff like your `timeit` call in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = timeit.timeit(...)

    print(t)
```

If you don't, then definitely import `from __main__` as opposed to `from test`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are including the test.py file twice once as `__main__` and once as `test` check it out!

```
#test.py

import timeit

def dictComp(I):
    return {x: x for x in I}

print __name__
t = timeit.timeit(number=5,
                  stmt='dictComp(I)',
                  setup='from test import dictComp\nI=range(1000000)')
print(t)
```